# learning to output custom rsyslogs

Tags: rsyslog

I've installed `rsyslog`. I want to log why my server is refusing to show my index page in the browser in

```
/var/log/browser.log
```

Should it be listening on a standard port? I can see `netstat -tpan`.

To be frank I need a good tutorial to set this up with editing `rsyslog.conf` as I am more familiar with coding than SSH Unix commands.

---

The logs error and access were handled by `virtualmin`. I uninstalled `virtualmin`, so that I could learn how to secure the server with pure config files.

Running `yum list installed` shows `httpd-tools.x86_64` highlighted in yellow as well as the webpage not being available - `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

Comment: What "server" are you referring to? Evidently it provides  HTTP(S)...why do you believe it uses syslog at all? This reeks of [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).

Comment: unix centos http. I see what you mean by xy, but my reasoning is rather than cry that I can't see a page (problem x), I should see If a log will show me what is happening (y)

Comment: By default Apache on CentoS maintains an `ErrorLog` in the default location of `/var/log/httpd/error_log`

Comment: "Httpd" *generally* refers to apache, but **always use the later** since it's clearer and more specific (the former *may* refer to other http server apps). In this case, you want to investigate how apache logging works, not the system logger; syslog is mostly used by the OS kernel and ubiquitous system related services (i.e., the stuff that makes apache possible, but as HBrujin points out, not apache itself).  There's the crux of your XY issue.

Comment: ...Another potential XY problem here is the assumption that there's a server error occurring -- usually apache will show a 500 page for that, if it hasn't it may not think anything is wrong.  So if you *don't* find anything in the logs, then you may want to ask a different question explaining the problem in detail (what actually happens in the browser when you try to load the page, etc.)

Comment: This webpage is not available - ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Answer (score 2):

Typically web servers do not output their log messages to syslog, but will write directly to their own log files.

Changing the location of the log files is specific to the web server software you're using.

E.g. Apache with which I'm most familiar is typically configured with at least two distinct log files, one specific for start-up and error messages and a second one with usage statistics which are configured with `ErrorLog` and `AccessLog` directives respectively. Edit the httpd.conf file and change it to read `ErrorLog /var/log/browser.log`

Converting the logging of your webserver from files to syslog messages may be possible as well.

In Apache that would mean changing the logging directives from files to pipe them through `logger` to convert them syslog messages.

```
ErrorLog "|/usr/bin/logger -p local4.warn "
```

Then the second stage is to configure your rsyslog daemon to write messages send to the "local4" facility with a status or "warn(ing)" to your custom log file. That may be as simple as editing the rsyslog configuration file and restarting the rsyslog daemon.

```
# /etc/rsyslog.conf
# ...
local4.warn  /var/log/browser.log
```

All of the above is interesting and it can be very useful to have a webserver use syslog to transmit log file entries to remote syslog server, especially in larger webserver clusters.

But that does not yet solve your problem of why your index page is not displayed....

Comment: I first went to the /var/log/httpd/access_log & error_log files (wiped them clean of old stuff), accessed the page, then went back to read any new log lines printed. but there are none, it is as if I am not visiting the page at all. would it help to move from warn to debug?

Comment: The default locations may not be correct, nor the only log files maintained by apache, especially when you used a control panel to manage your system. Inspect the main apache configuration (typically `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`) and all additional configuration files that may be sourced with `Include` directives. (again often, but not guaranteed to be in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/`)